# How To Share .Mobi file to iBooks App using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-sharing, ibooks

I am implementing sharing option in iOS using xamarin to share .Mobi files. I have referred the code from https://xamarinhelp.com/share-dialog-xamarin-forms/. I can able to share the file to drop box, kindle and other supported apps. iBooks is not listed when share .Mobi file. But iBooks app is listed when share .PDF file. iBooks will not support Mobi files? if it supports .Mobi file what should be done from my side to list ibooks app in sharing list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the blog mentioned,

> This could include sharing with, Facebook, Email, SMS or any other app that has registered support for the file type. For example PDF readers can handle a PDF, or Facebook and other apps would be able to share image files.

refer to [ibooks on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBooks), scroll down and look at the **Formats** , iBooks only support `EPUB` , `PDF` and `IBA` format.